# sun JVM crash during Java_java_net_NetworkInterface_getAll

Tags: java, network-programming, jvm-crash

Selenium-server queries all network interfaces at start time; unfortunately this causes a JVM memory corruption and hard crash of the JVM on my Ubuntu machine.  This is reproducable on this machine by any java process calling java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()

Some things about the OS:

```
2.6.35-30-generic #59-Ubuntu SMP
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)

This machine has a number of virtual network interfaces and some static routes:
    virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:de:be:41:c2:23 
    tap248    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:9e:b3:46:48:b9
```

And the grease

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role node -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register
>
> ```
> Mar 30, 2012 9:14:05 AM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
> ```
>
> INFO: Launching a selenium grid node

```
*** glibc detected *** java: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00007ffec0144cc0 ***

======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x774b6)[0x7ffecd56e4b6]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x73)[0x7ffecd574c83]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so(+0x5a96)[0x7ffec58dba96]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so(Java_java_net_NetworkInterface_getAll+0x8c)[0x7ffec58daf9c]
[0x7ffec87e3d6e]
======= Memory map: ========
40000000-40009000 r-xp 00000000 08:41 4473913                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/bin/java
40108000-4010a000 rwxp 00008000 08:41 4473913                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/bin/java
```

Comment: So what is your question?  Do you want us to tell you how to report a Java bug to Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

It *could be* this Java bug - https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7078386